# What is the sorting order when a collection contains character,integer and string in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a doubt in sorting preference when a collection contains character,Integer and string in it. how the sorting order works when it have this kind of data. ex: `['a',2,3,5,'b',ab","def"]` and how it will sort this data and what is the logic it will use to sort this data.

Comment: A single Java collection typically _can't_ support these multiple of data, not unless you use something like `List<Object>`, which is a raw collection and is not recommended.  Maybe add your current Java code to your question.

Comment: Hi @Satish - tim is right - and what collection are you using [or is this a hypothetical ...] suspect it might be the order of comparing `.toString()` ..

Comment: @tim, Yeah it's a List<Object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have certain doubts you may always do a try:

Attempt #1: Let's sort a list of objects

```java
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList('a',2,3,5,'b',"ab","def");
      
Collections.sort(list);
```

Result:

```
error: no suitable method found for sort(List<Object>)
      Collections.sort(list);
                 ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: Object
        lower bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
```

So, plain `List<Object>` cannot be sorted as is.

Attempt #2.  All the objects in the given example are `Comparable`, so let's try to sort them:

```java
List<Comparable> list = Arrays.asList('a',2,3,5,'b',"ab","def");
      
Collections.sort(list);
```

It does not work either:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Character cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Character and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1249)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1436)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.sort(Arrays.java:4405)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:145)
```

Thus, the objects in the list should not be just `Comparable`, their types have to be "compatible"

Attempt #3.  Use some of existing method of `Object` to compare the objects (e.g. `toString` or `hashCode`)

```java
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList('a',2,3,5,'b',"ab","def");
      
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Object::hashCode));

System.out.println("Sorted by hashCode: " + list);
      
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString));
      
System.out.println("Sorted by toString: " + list);
```

Output:

```
Sorted by hashCode: [2, 3, 5, a, b, ab, def]
Sorted by toString: [2, 3, 5, a, ab, b, def]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and now i got how it works.